# AngularJS Devise authorization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise

I'm trying to add authorization functionality to my app, sow for example when I want to go to /admin/posts/create it will redirect me to /login if I'm not already logged in.

**My angular module**

```
angular.module('flapperNews', ['ui.router', 'templates', 'ngResource', 'formly', 'formlyBootstrap', 'ngMessages', 'Devise'])
```

**I'm using this service**
  angular.module('flapperNews')
  .factory('authorization', [
    '$state',
    'Auth',
    '$location',
    function($state, Auth, $location) {

```
  return {
    authorize: function() {
      var isAuthenticated = Auth.isAuthenticated();

      if (isAuthenticated === false) {
        $state.go('login');
      }

    }
  };

}
```

]);

**These are my routes**

```
 $stateProvider.state('home', {
        url: '/',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'posts/_posts.html'
    });

    $stateProvider.state('admin', {
        abstract: true,
        resolve: {
            authorize: ['authorization', function(authorization) {
                return authorization.authorize();
            }]
        },
        template: '<div ui-view />'
    });

    $stateProvider.state('postsCreate', {
        parent: 'admin',
        url: '/admin/posts/create',
        controller: 'PostsCtrl as vm',
        templateUrl: 'posts/create.html'
    });
```

**Through this link I'm trying to access route where I shouldn't be able to get**

```
<a ui-sref="postsCreate" class="btn btn-primary">Create a post</a>
```

I don't get any errors and I end up in section which I should be able to access.